# Issue with launching a new class when clicked on a element in Gridview Android

Tags: android

I have a piece of code that when I clicked on image element in a gridview I want to launch the new class Popup. However, it clashed when I do that right now. what's wrong?

`Method onCreate():`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    mAdapter=new ImageAdapter(this);

    final Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();

    gridview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(

        new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Popup.class);
            startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    );
```

`Class Popup`:

```
public class Popup extends Activity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected " +"item",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      

    }   

}
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".GridView2Activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".Popup"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: You should be getting an error message in `logcat`, please check out the `DDMS`-tab and update your post.

Comment: Error Message 11-09 16:51:32.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2176): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.GridView2/com.GridView2.GridView2Activity$Popup}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I have  <activity android:name="Popup" android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity> in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Try changing `android:name="Popup"` to `android:name=".Popup"`. :)

Comment: Ok, I did try to change the name to .Popup but it still crashed, same error message as above.

Comment: Could you update your post with the contents of your  `androidmanifest.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Passing application context creates problem usually ,no idea why so . 
replace ctx by className.this .

Also share error log and more detail about crash , so that we can help you more .

Comment: Yes, I did try that.  final Intent i = new Intent(GridView2Activity.this, Popup.class);
 startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest, check that your package is correct.
it could be your package for Popup class differ from GridView2Activity. 
if they differ put the exact package path

Comment: yes, I did try that.  <activity android:name="com.GridView2.Popup"></activity>

Comment: if u r confident that the manifest is declared correctly. another thing u can try is to uninstall your app from your test device and redeploy it again. 
there would be times when eclipse doesn't deploy new codes correctly which sometimes i do face. .